# storing drupal field data and retrieve with validation drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

in drupal 7

what is the best way to store the input value and field name in database and restore it later .

And also if i get that then can i validate those data in listing page

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it by storing whole $form_state in db.